# Circuitikz: npn error

Tags: circuitikz, tikz-node

I try to do some schematics with circuitikz. The result is as expected, but I always get errors from pdflatex and can not figure out what causes these annoying errors.

I installed the most recent circuitikz package (0.7, issued on 2016-09-08).

Here ist my (unfortunately not working) minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) -- (2,0) node[circ] {} to[zD-, v^<=$U_\mathrm{Z}$] (2,2) node[circ] {} to [R, l=$R_1$](2,4) -- (0,4);
    \draw (4,4) node[npn,rotate=90](npn1) {};
    \draw (2,4) node[circ] {} -- (npn1.C);
    \draw (2,2) -- (4,2) node[circ] {} -- (npn1.B);
    \draw (2,0) -- (4,0) -- (4,0.5) to [C, l_=$C_1$] (4,2);
    \draw (4,0) node[circ] {} -- (6,0);
    \draw (npn1.E) -- (6,4);
    \draw [-latex'] (0,3.5) -- (0,0.5) node[anchor=east] at (0,2){$U_\mathrm{E}$};
    \draw [-latex'] (6,3.5) -- (6,0.5) node[anchor=west] at (6,2){$U_\mathrm{A}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The logfile always shows:

l.10 ...] (2,2) node[circ] {} to R, l=$R_1$ -- (0,4);

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type`I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

Hope someone has a hint what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Can you check the version of circuitikz being loaded in compilation? In the log file there should be a line like `Package: circuitikz <date> <version>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce your error. So the first advise is to upgrade your `circuit` to recent one. The second, in spirit of `circuit your drawing can be drawn as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) to[short,-*] (2,0)
            to[zD-, v^<=$U_\mathrm{Z}$,-*] (2,2)
            to [R, l=$R_1$,-*] (2,4) -- (0,4)
      (4,4) node[npn,rotate=90](npn1) {}
      (2,4) -- (npn1.C)
      (npn1.E) -- (6,4)
      (npn1.B) to[short,-*] (4,2)
               to [C, l_=$C_1$,-*] (4,0)
      (2,2) -- (4,2)
      (2,0) -- (6,0);
\draw [-latex'] (0,3.5) -- node[anchor=east] {$U_\mathrm{E}$} (0,0.5);
\draw [-latex'] (6,3.5) -- node[anchor=west] {$U_\mathrm{A}$} (6,0.5);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Probably the input and output terminals should have circles.

[image]

In this case you need to use `[short,o-]` and `[short,-o]` instead `--` on input/output lines:

```
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) to[short,o-*] (2,0)
            to[zD-, v^<=$U_\mathrm{Z}$,-*] (2,2)
            to [R, l=$R_1$,-*] (2,4) 
            to[short,-o] (0,4)
      (4,4) node[npn,rotate=90](npn1) {}
      (2,4) -- (npn1.C)
      (npn1.E) to[short,-o] (6,4)
      (npn1.B) to[short,-*] (4,2)
               to [C, l_=$C_1$,-*] (4,0)
      (2,2) -- (4,2)
      (2,0) to[short,-o] (6,0);
\draw [-latex'] (0,3.5) -- node[anchor=east] {$U_\mathrm{E}$} (0,0.5);
\draw [-latex'] (6,3.5) -- node[anchor=west] {$U_\mathrm{A}$} (6,0.5);
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment and the hint for circles at the i/o-terminals. Too bad that you can not reproduce the error. As mentioned, everything works, but the error message is annoying.

Comment: no, no, it is not  bad at all :). this means, that your drawing -- as you show in question -- is not a cause of error (the first image is generated by your code using my MikTeX ). Check, if you have installed recent versions of packages. I hope that other changes in my MWE can help you in future circuits drawing.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. The solution given is working. I was stuck due to old TeXlive packages in the Ubuntu repositories. After updating all the circuitikz-related files, everything is working. Thanks for your hints anyway!